# How to improve performance for resources.getDrawable

Tags: java, android, performance, garbage-collection

I have an activity that loads three png images. On hdpi they are 20kb, 148kb, and 190kb. Here's the code I'm loading them with:

```
Drawable bronzePlaque = resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.bronze_plaque);
Drawable silverPlaque = resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.silver_plaque);
Drawable goldPlaque = resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.gold_plaque);
```

Those calls alone seem to take about 500 ms, which causes a noticeable lag when loading that activity.

I'm not sure how much of the time that takes is due to the pictures' size, vs. garbage collection / heap size growing, but I'd like to try to do something to improve it. Is there a way I can get the virtual machine to properly grow the heap and garbage collect only once for those three allocations?

Here's the logcat output for those three lines (and for the system print `getTimeInMillis` around them).

```
03-23 14:05:57.260: I/System.out(30302): time: 1395608757267
03-23 14:05:57.370: D/dalvikvm(30302): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 39K, 4% free 7990K/8272K, paused 20ms, total 20ms
03-23 14:05:57.370: I/dalvikvm-heap(30302): Grow heap (frag case) to 8.968MB for 1188160-byte allocation
03-23 14:05:57.390: D/dalvikvm(30302): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1K, 4% free 9149K/9436K, paused 19ms, total 19ms
03-23 14:05:57.540: D/dalvikvm(30302): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1K, 4% free 9148K/9436K, paused 15ms, total 16ms
03-23 14:05:57.540: I/dalvikvm-heap(30302): Grow heap (frag case) to 10.245MB for 1340008-byte allocation
03-23 14:05:57.560: D/dalvikvm(30302): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 3% free 10457K/10748K, paused 19ms, total 19ms
03-23 14:05:57.720: D/dalvikvm(30302): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 3% free 10457K/10748K, paused 15ms, total 15ms
03-23 14:05:57.720: I/dalvikvm-heap(30302): Grow heap (frag case) to 11.482MB for 1297384-byte allocation
03-23 14:05:57.740: D/dalvikvm(30302): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 3% free 11724K/12016K, paused 18ms, total 18ms
03-23 14:05:57.760: I/System.out(30302): time: 1395608757770
```

I know that after that activity has been loaded once it's much faster loading the activity later. Should I maybe load those images once at app load time to help prevent painful heap growing / garbage collecting? I'd rather have that half a second of lag front-loaded than experienced when clicking the activity.

Comment: What size are the images?

Comment: 750x502 px -- 20kb, 750x567 px -- 149kb, and 750x549 px -- 190kb. They are background images for a scrollview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try loading these images from another thread (i.e. not main) instead. Besides the ~100ms spent in gc, the rest of the 500 ms is spent on loading the data from file system and uncompressing JPG data into Bitmaps.

> I know that after that activity has been loaded once it's much faster
>   loading the activity later. Should I maybe load those images once at
>   app load time to help prevent painful heap growing / garbage
>   collecting?

Unless you purposefully held-on to the decoded Bitmaps, otherwise Resources is free to release any cached Drawable/Bitmap it sees fit. Note that the images will take up 750x502x4 + 750x567x4 + 750x549x4 =~4.5 MB RAM, purposefully holding onto them may have other ramifications such as OoM on older devices (Nexus One only has a max of 16 MB RAM per process/app) and may cause your app to be evicted from memory sooner when it's in the background and the OS needs more RAM.

Comment: Yeah, I don't want to actually hold onto them. For now I'm just loading them in the onCreate method for the application, which seems to inconsistently reduce the pain a little bit. The activity can't really display until they're loaded, so loading them on another thread wouldn't do much good unless I want to make a loading animation or something.

Comment: @CorayThan If you are really keen on reducing the loading time and this Activity is not the main Activity, you can load raw file data into memory as byte[] so you don't have to load them when that particular Activity is started. Obviously before going down this path you should check the file-reading portion to make sure the benefit is there.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you are a bit out of luck. You can not increase the heap on Android as you wish (unlike in a normal JVM process). See [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=14869) Still 4 MB images is too much.

And it seems like u have the solution already, load them upfront.